# Objective C Static Library with Pod Dependencies swift file error

Tags: objective-c, swift, static, frameworks

I have a static library that is used by two of my projects. This static library is using CocoaLumberjack and RNCryptor. They worked fine before but after I updated the pods they now have a swift file and this causes an error "Swift is not supported for static libraries.". The static library is in Objective-C, one of the projects using it is also in Objective-C, while the other one is in Swift.

I've read other questions and found that most of them say to change the static library to framework. How do I actually do that? Or is there another way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to uninstall the pod first. Afterwards reinstall the pod, but make sure you include in your Podfile before installing:

```
use_frameworks!
```